# I cannot create a function pointer of a function that returns a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I would like to call a function from a dynamic library at run-time. That function returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated object (I simplified the code below to an int).
I would like the code below to store this pointer to this object to use the object as I please.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <memory>

/* myFunction() is supposed to be in my dynamic library */
std::unique_ptr<int> myFunction()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<int>(new(int));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *(*functionPtr)() = nullptr;

    void *handle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    int *symbolAddress = static_cast<int *>(dlsym(handle, "myFunction"));

    *(int **)(&functionPtr) = symbolAddress;

    int *x = functionPtr();
    //std::unique_ptr<int> x = functionPtr();

    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles but I wrote that the return type of the function myFunction is "int *" (in the main function) which is not the case in the function declaration in my library.

PS : In the post, I call "object" the type "int" to simplify, in my example.
My final goal would be to uncomment the last line.

I might be doing the wrong thing. I'm still learning the langage but I would like to code properly so I am open to restructure my code.

Comment: A `unique_pointer<int>` is not the same thing as an `int*`, your function pointer type is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `myFunction` is `std::unique_ptr<int> ()`. The type of a pointer to `myFunction` is thus `std::unique_ptr<int> (*)()`. That is exactly how `functionPtr` should be declared:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> (*functionPtr)();
```

---

Additionally:

> ```
> *(int **)(&functionPtr) = symbolAddress;
> ```

This kind of a type-punned write violates strict aliasing in C and C++ alike, and I'm not sure why `symbolAddress` is `int *` to begin with. Your code should probably look like:

```
void *symbolAddress = dlsym(handle, "myFunction");
functionPtr = (std::unique_ptr<int>(*)())symbolAddress;
```

Comment: `*(int **)(&functionPtr) = symbolAddress;` "violates strict aliasing" is a very mild way of putting it. It is way worse than that.

Comment: And for the sake of simplicity, `functionPtr = static_cast<decltype(functionPtr)>(symbolAddress)`